# Preserve line breaks when binding textarea content to md-card

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

I have a textarea and a md-card.

```js
angular.module('dashboard', ['ngMaterial'])
  .config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
      .dark()
      .primaryPalette('indigo')
      .accentPalette('yellow');
  })
  .controller('previewCtrl', function() {
    //previewCtrl = this;
    this.previewData = previewData;
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="dashboard">
  <textarea required type="text" rows="5" ng-model="form.text"></textarea>

  <md-card class="md-whiteframe-9dp card-noimage">
    <md-card-title>
      <md-card-title-text>
        <span class="md-headline">Title</span>
        <span class="md-subhead">Sub heading</span>
      </md-card-title-text>
    </md-card-title>
    <md-card-content ng-bind="form.text">
    </md-card-content>
  </md-card>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the text typed in the textarea in to the `md-card` 's content area.

**Problem -**  Whenever I type `<br>` or `\n` in the textarea the card shows "
" and "\n" instead of showing a newline. I want to show newlines instead of them

Comment: Can you try using the `ng-bind-html` attribute instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inject HTML into through AngularJS, you could use `ng-bind-html` directive instead of `ng-bind`.

It requires you to inject the `ngSanitize` module into your app and import it's JS file first

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

This way, the text is understood as html. So, a `<br>` tag will be rendered as a new line.

But `\n` isn't HTML, so you could create a filter to replace it with a `<br>` tag like this:

```
app.filter('newLines', function () {
    return function(text) {
        if(text)
            return text.replace(/\\n/g, '<br/>');
    };
});
```

Now you could use the `ng-bind-html` directive and the `newLines` filter like this:

```
<md-card-content ng-bind-html="form.text | newLines">
</md-card-content>
```

---

Here's your code after applying the above modifications:

```js
angular.module('dashboard', ['ngMaterial', 'ngSanitize'])
  .config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
      .dark()
      .primaryPalette('indigo')
      .accentPalette('yellow');
  })
  .controller('previewCtrl', function() {
    //previewCtrl = this;
    this.previewData = previewData;
  })
  .filter('newLines', function () {
      return function(text) {
          if(text)
              return text.replace(/\\n/g, '<br/>');
      };
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="dashboard">
  <textarea required type="text" rows="5" ng-model="form.text"></textarea>

  <md-card class="md-whiteframe-9dp card-noimage">
    <md-card-title>
      <md-card-title-text>
        <span class="md-headline">Title</span>
        <span class="md-subhead">Sub heading</span>
      </md-card-title-text>
    </md-card-title>
    <md-card-content ng-bind-html="form.text | newLines">
    </md-card-content>
  </md-card>
</div>
```